# VLOOKUP is not finding text value on other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, vlookup

See [this example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NQ0JacsrbkurB2fQ3DCJGnEFXM0v9KSTUscV4HR2Vrw/edit?usp=sharing).

I get `#N/A` value when I try to find `bbb` on `sheet2` using formula `=VLOOKUP(A1;sheet2!$A$1:$B$4;1;FALSE)`

How to fix it?

Comment: While including a demo spreadsheet is helpful, questions should be self contained. In other words, add the formula an a sample of the data to the question itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`VLOOKUP`** is able to look for something only if that something is in the first column of the lookup. In your case is **`bbb`** in the second column of the range **`A1:B4`** you looking for. Fix is:

- switch **A** column with **B** column on your **`sheet2`**
- exclude **A** column from range: **`=VLOOKUP(A1; sheet2!B1:B; 1; 0)`**
- use: **`=VLOOKUP(A1; {sheet2!B1:B\sheet2!A1:B}; 1; 0)`**

Comment: In my real sheet I can not switch the order of the columns, and I have multiple columns in the table between the source and target columns. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @klor yes. check the 3rd fix... with it you can virtually move the B column to be the first column

Comment: It seems to work. See demo table. Could you explain deeply in the answer how to move a column virtually? What is the syntax rule? Thanks!

Comment: @klor I can try... your actual data are in a table in `sheet2!A1:B` - let's call this table "the real one" because you have 2 columns (A and B) and you refer to this with range `sheet2!`**A1:B**. however, in the 3rd fix, we need to use `{sheet2!B1:B\sheet2!A1:B}` as a range instead of `sheet2!A1:B` eg. with these array brackets `{}` we can construct virtual table where 1st column is B 2nd column is A and 3rd column is B. its like we virtually appended B column to real table just for purpose to VLOOKUP be able to work. paste this in some cell and see what's going on `={sheet2!B1:B\sheet2!A1:B}`

Comment: Your solution seems to work fine in test environment. See here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NQ0JacsrbkurB2fQ3DCJGnEFXM0v9KSTUscV4HR2Vrw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Waiting for peer review my edit.

Comment: (V)LOOKUP does not work well with values other then numbers. Expect the unexpected while looking-up text values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample copy of your sheet: [Index-Match](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jEY9RYJghx1NaDORZgz-6VzIghBW3ygKp2tyEz4Vh34/edit?usp=sharing)

I suggest, instead of a VLookup, you use a Index/Match variant. This will allow you to search by any row, to return any column. Here's how:

The Match Function will return the row # of a specific column. You use this within the next function to create a crosshair target focusing on your desired value.

```
=(MATCH(A4;sheet2!B:B))
```

Where A4 is your lookup value, sheet2!B:B the column you're using to return the row # (your vertical crosshair).

You nest that inside the Index function which will return your horizontal crosshair and the value where the two points intersect:

`=(INDEX(sheet2!A:B;###;1))`

Where sheet2!A:B is your lookup range, ### is your row number, and 1 is the column from which you want a value returned (left to right columns are counted numerically 1 through however many columns you have in your specified range).

Where ### can be replaced by either the row number of the value you want returned or the match function above (MATCH(A4;sheet2!B:B)).

This way, you don't have to clean your data, you can just run searches with your crosshair and find your data.

Comment: I added some examples/tests to the demo table, and your formula fails in some conditions. Additionally your one is more difficult to remember, when I will need it again.

Comment: See here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NQ0JacsrbkurB2fQ3DCJGnEFXM0v9KSTUscV4HR2Vrw/edit?usp=sharing